# Opening a file by double-clicking

Tags: java, file, mouselistener, double-click

I am new to programming and I am working on a Java IED which opens Java files. I want it so that when you double click a .java file it is automatically opened with the program, but I have not been able to figure it out. I am working on Mac, any tips or examples on how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: As in associate a specific file type with your program? Isn't that handled at the OS level?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Dependent upon the OS (windows, linux, mac)

Comment: @MasterBlaster  Mac.

Comment: @MatthewDiana yes to open a specific file type. Also I don't think so because the way it is now when I double-click the associated file type, it opens my program but not the file.